# Scala class substitution

Tags: java, scala, aop, substitution

There is a Java library with classes:

```
class DefaultFieldFactory {
  ...
  public static String createCaptionByPropertyId(Object propertyId) { ... }
  ...
}

class FieldFactory extends DefaultFieldFactory {
  ...
  // Lot of methods that use DefaultFieldFactory.createCaptionByPropertyId
  ...
}
```

I am using the FieldFactory class in a Scala project and I need to alter createCaptionByPropertyId method.

How can I do it without AOP and rewriting the FieldFactory class?

Is it possible to substitute DefaultFieldFactory class implementation in package? It is relatively simple and short.

Thanks in advance,
Etam.

Comment: You cannot **override** `static` methods.

Comment: I don't wan't to **override** it, I'd like to force FieldFactory to use my implementation of createCaptionByPropertyId method.

Comment: @Etam That's called overriding.

Answer (score 2):

A static class would go into an `object` in Scala, which would not inherit the static methods of `DefaultFieldFactory` -- which, in fact, reflects well the fact that you can't override statics.

This is one reason why statics are frowned upon.

Comment: OK, I know that, but what I am asking is - you can replace somehow the method in a class, in this case a static class.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a hacky way to do it... But if you have the source code for the original java class I would strongly recommend you change it.

If not you can create a new implementation of `DefaultFieldFactory` as an object in your class that hides the  original implementation within your class.  Then the implementation of the `DefaultFieldFactory` object can call through to the original java implimentations.

```
// in package x.y.a
class DefaultFieldFactory {
  ...
  public static String createCaptionByPropertyId(Object propertyId) { ... }
  ...
}

// in package x.y.b
class FieldFactory extends DefaultFieldFactory {

  object DefaultFieldFactory{


    def createCaptionByPropertyId(propertyId: AnyRef): String { 
      //import the original implimentation
      import x.y.b.DefaultFieldFactory._
      ... 
    }
  }


  // Lot of methods that use DefaultFieldFactory.createCaptionByPropertyId
  ...
}
```

Like I say... not nice!